# How can I perform shell-safe escaping on a variable in Ansible?

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2

Consider the following Ansible task:

```yaml
- name: "Install Python packages"
  ansible.builtin.pip:
    name:
      - "foobar"
    extra_args: "--no-index --find-links=file://{{ role_path }}/files/pip/"
```

This task installs a Python package from a pre-downloaded package file which is stored with the Ansible role.

However, there is a gotcha here: if the path on disk where the Ansible role is located contains whitespace or a backslash, the `--find-links` argument will be parsed incorrectly.

What I need is some form of filter or function which will apply the equivalent of `printf '%q'` to the `{{ role_path }}` variable, escaping all whitespace or special characters. Is there such a function in Ansible or Jinja2?

Answer (score 0):

Found it: `{{ role_path | quote }}`